# Check if MySQL server is able to accept connections

Tags: php, mysql, connection

What is the best way to check, from PHP, if connection to a MySQL server will succeed? I've seen some solutions that first try to open a socket connection (with `fsockopen`) and connect to MySQL (via whatever extension you are using) only if the socket connection was successful. I'm not too sure about this since you have to make two connections every time, does that hammer the server too much?

My problem is that if my MySQL server locks-up or stops working for whatever reason the web page just stops working (it load for a long time and then usually comes back with a 504 gateway time-out error). I'd like to display a user friendly error message if MySQL is not available. This would also, hopefully, avoid MySQL being hammered even more if it is already struggling, as new clients won't connect to it until the server comes back up.

I'm using [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/mysqli) extension if that is relevant.

Comment: Shouldn't a mySQL connection attempt time out relatively quickly when failing?

Comment: depends on connect_timeout setting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your need is the `MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT` specify in mysqli::options
[details](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php)

Comment: Ok this helps the time-out to happen sooner. But I'm still worried that a MySQLi connection is more expensive for MySQL server than a `fsockopen` check. Any thoughts?

Comment: Using the fsockopen, IMHO - Two is greater than one.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

/*
 * This is the "official" OO way to do it,
 * BUT $connect_error was broken until PHP 5.2.9 and 5.3.0.
 */
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

/*
 * Use this instead of $connect_error if you need to ensure
 * compatibility with PHP versions prior to 5.2.9 and 5.3.0.
 */
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo 'Success... ' . $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect.php

Comment: This will give me an error after the MySqli extension will wait for god know how long to try to connect. I need to know if I'll be able to connect before I do a `new MySqli ...`